# Wrong top margin in "Flagging>Closing>Off-topic" modal

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Take a look on the screenshot: description of every option available is shifted some 5 pixels downwards comparing to the radio-buttons.

OS X 10.10.5, Google Chrome 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit)
[image]

Comment: I'm able to duplicate this in Firefox 50.1.0 on Meta using the same Flag > Closing > Off-Topic path. (The top margin on the previous modal views are OK.)

Comment: It seems to have special CSS, probably because it has no header: `.close-as-off-topic-pane .action-name { [...] margin: 5px; }`

Comment: Marking this as a duplicate of a newer question, since that's the one that's been answered by the person who fixed the bug.