# Close dialog radios misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, close-reasons

The 2nd level of close reason's radio buttons are misaligned. Chrome, Windows 10, 4k screen.

[image]

Comment: It's caused by the `margin` on `.close-as-off-topic-pane .action-name`.

Comment: looks like its been broken again: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340234/wrong-top-margin-in-flaggingclosingoff-topic-modal

Comment: I can replicate this on Chrome 60, Windows 7 on a 1280*1024 screen, so not a high-DPI issue

Comment: Freehand circles??

Comment: Ah yes, CSS and vertical alignment. A continual source of "fun".

Comment: @alexanderbird: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvQMJ.png there you go

Comment: @MatteoItalia you seem to be a pro at Freehand drawing :D

Answer (score 5):

I've cleaned up that layout a little bit, so this should look better from the next build on. Not great, mind you, but a little bit better. A little birdy told me there may be some [design work in progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3vdW.png) to make all the popups nicer and more consistent, but no promise on a timeline here.

Comment: Consistency with the old design would also be desirable. Please don't move our cheese from one side of the dialog to the other without a good reason.

Comment: Related post in MSE [Alignment issue in the Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289054/312043). If the alignment issue was fixed, can that post's status will be changed?

Comment: @Arulkumar Sure, will do, thanks!