# LQP Delete reason radios misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, design, flag-dialog

I saw that the radios for the Close reasons was [fixed today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356597/1007939). However, now I'm seeing a huge misalignment on the Low Quality Posts Delete reasons popup. I don't know if they're related, but I thought I should point it out.

Using Chrome Dev Tools, it looks like it's the `display: block;` in `.action-list:not(.popup-condensed) li>label`, which is applied to the label and description text for the delete reason.

FWIW this is happening on the Suggested Edit Reject reason as well

[image]

Comment: This is also happening in the moderator flag response dialog. Same offset.

Comment: This has also been reported on MSE - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301479/misalignment-with-radio-buttons-in-add-comment-dialog-in-lqp-queue

Comment: @BradLarson Fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed now, see [Misalignment with radio buttons in add comment dialog in LQP queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301479/misalignment-with-radio-buttons-in-add-comment-dialog-in-lqp-queue/301498#301498).