# Labels misaligned, reject reason modal

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, design

On the rejection form for an edit the label is shown below the radio button instead of along side.

OS: Windows 10
Browser: Google Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Be on a question.
2. Question has a pending edit.
3. Reject the pending edit.
4. When the dialog loads the labels are not aligned as in the picture below.

[image: labels below radio button]

Comment: The label has `display: block;`. It probably shouldn't have that.

Comment: strongly related: [LQP Delete reason radios misaligned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357221/839601); possibly this is yet another side effect of [this recent change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301492/165773)

Comment: Please don't close these reports as dupes unless they're referring to exactly the same popup.

Comment: @balpha did they not have the same root cause?

Comment: @Stijn Yeah, and I'm not blaming anyone for voting to close -- but technically each popup is an issue that needs to be fixed separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed now, see [Misalignment with radio buttons in add comment dialog in LQP queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301479/misalignment-with-radio-buttons-in-add-comment-dialog-in-lqp-queue/301498#301498).

Comment: Continuing the saga of all the dialog boxes are different and one tweak has unexpected spillover effects... [The close dialog has overlapping text when a vote has been cast in one of the categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42h8r.png), and the "info" tab in the "mod" pop-up dialog is exhibiting similar symptoms.

Comment: *whack-a-bug*, a fun and exciting game for developers of all ages