# Text overlap in vote to close dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-dialog

There seems to be an overlap of text in vote to close dialog in the case of <s>**Off topic**</s> *any* option when there is a pre-existing vote from another user on that option.

Below is the snapshot:

[image]

This does not occur if there is 0 votes on the section.

This is in latest version of Chrome in Mac OS Sierra.

Comment: Can confirm this is an issue in current Firefox too.

Comment: It's doing it *again?* - It was fine earlier. LOL. First it was messed up, then they fixed and now it's messed up again.

Comment: Repro on Firefox, too. [Poked a dev about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357231/labels-misaligned-reject-reason-modal#comment518303_357235).

Comment: Can reproduce. Win7 pro 64 bit latest chrome.   As you stated it's only happening to reasons that have close votes associated to them.

Comment: On main meta as well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301503/misaligned-options-still-in-the-close-vote-popup-dialog

Comment: The history of this is hilarious: [20 hours ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356597) → [16 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301479) → [2 hours ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357231) → [10 minutes ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357243/).

Comment: @poke that is weird. lets hope this is the final chapter of the sage

Comment: This is fixed in the code already, I'll deploy it shortly (original report [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357231/labels-misaligned-reject-reason-modal/357235?noredirect=1#comment518303_357235)).

Comment: strongly related: [Thousands of errors!](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/322682/31260) @poke

Comment: Reproduced for me too on Version 61.0.3163.91 (Official Build) (64-bit), Fedora 26 (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357248/2422776, thanks @Tom for closing!)